# Grails realization relationships

Tags: grails, orm, groovy

Could you please help me. I am new in Grails. I have read grails doc, but did not find answer for my questions.

**class Customer:**
    package test

```
    class Customer {
        int points
        static hasMany = [pr:Product]
        List pr;
        static constraints = {
        }
    }
```

**class Product:**

```
package test
class Product {
    String question
    int points
    static belongsTo = [c:Customer]
    static constraints = {
    }
```

As we can see there is a one to many relation.
Then I want to add a lot of Products to one customer:

```
    def cust = new Customer()
    def pr = new Product();
    cust.pr=new ArrayList();
    cust.pr.add(pr);
```

Is this correct realization?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default when you define a relationship with GORM it is a java.util.

[Answer](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.4%20Sets,%20Lists%20and%20Maps)